# MSMQ find a particular returning message

Tags: c#, client-server, message-queue, msmq

Intention : I want to create a console, after the console execute the first queue, they will generate something like receipe data and throw into the second queue, another console , they will grab the data from the second queue and execute.

The thing is, what if the second queue have one million records. I dont want to loop one million record and throw it back and it will consume big usage of the server and it is not efficiency.

Is it able to, given a self generated id to the label, and find the particular message with one code?

for example, datatable tempDt;

tempDt.Select("id = '"+id+"'");

something like this

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t877y0k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): you can use

```
queue.ReceiveById(...);
```

to get a specific message. From the msdn page:
"Use this method to read a message with a known identifier and remove it from the queue."

Not a self-generated id, but may be useful to you...